# MariaDB - how to query on POINT field for locations inside lat/lng coordinates for a given city/area?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial

I consider myself quite good with SQL but I am just stumped on how to even begin to perform this type of search.

It seems like quite a simple scenario - I have a MariaDB database already populated with several records with their location point stored in a POINT data field ("POINT NOT NULL"). I then want to query the database for all entities that are within a given lat/lng. For example, the latitude and longitude for New York City is 40.730610 and -73.935242.

I assume I should be using [`ST_within()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st-within/) but I have no idea how I would create the query... in that example, it uses `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((175 150, 20 40, 50 60, 125 100, 175 150))')` but I have no idea as to how I would construct the POLYGON or if that is even the solution I am looking for.

If anyone can help or point in the direction of a resource explaining it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: A pair of lat/long coordinates mark a point, not an area. No other point can fall within a point. You either have to get NY City area as a polygon or you have to make an assumption that points within X miles/kms radius from the lat/long coordinates fall within NYC.

Comment: But perhaps not so good with google? ;-)